# jQuery animation interrupted

Tags: jquery, animation, ember.js

I have a simple animation that works using just jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.right-block').on('click', 'chevron', function() {
    if ($('.activity').hasClass('extended')) {
      $('.activity').removeClass('extended').addClass('normal');
      $('.extended-block').slideUp();
      $('footer').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('.activity').addClass('extended').removeClass('normal');
      $('.extended-block').slideDown();
      $('footer').fadeIn();
    }      
  });

});
```

You can see it in action if you like here: http://cdpn.io/3bfea533af106c9bb601626be55eb3c1

When I try and do the same thing in Ember though things get a little funny. The animation starts, it reverses, it restarts, etc. It often completes after a lot of to and froing but state transition is not gauranteed it may end up in the same state you started in.

My Ember Component looks like this:

```
App.ActivityWidgetComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    actions: {
        toggleWidgetState: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.$('.right-block').on('click', 'chevron', function() {
                Ember.run.next(this, function() {
                    if (self.$('.activity').hasClass('extended')) {
                        self.$('.activity').removeClass('extended').addClass('normal');
                        self.$('.extended-block').slideUp();
                        self.$('footer').fadeOut();
                    } else {
                        self.$('.activity').addClass('extended').removeClass('normal');
                        self.$('.extended-block').slideDown();
                        self.$('footer').fadeIn();
                    }      
                }); 
            });
        }
    }

});
```

My sneaking suspicion is that this has something to do with "run-loop" dark arts. That's why you see my attempt to be "tricky" by adding the jQuery to the next run-loop. That change did seem to improve the behaviour a little but but it's definitely not solved it (and I'm not really sure if it was a step in the right direction).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the action of the component is just adding a jquery event listener, that will perform the jquery animation, not triggering it. You can replace your component with this:

```
App.ActivityWidgetComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    actions: {
        toggleWidgetState: function() {                                      
            if (this.$('.activity').hasClass('extended')) {
                this.$('.activity').removeClass('extended').addClass('normal');
                this.$('.extended-block').slideUp();
                this.$('footer').fadeOut();
            } else {
                this.$('.activity').addClass('extended').removeClass('normal');
                this.$('.extended-block').slideDown();
                this.$('footer').fadeIn();
            }                                  
        }
    }

});
```

And in your template, trigger this action using the `action` view helper:

```
  ...
  <div {{action "toggleWidgetState"}}  class="right-block">
    <chevron>&nbsp; &nbsp;</chevron>
  </div>
  ...
```

This is a live sample with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/H9XYd/

Comment: Ok, I already had the action statement. So basically you're saying remove the jQuery click event because there's already an Ember one. Makes good sense.

Comment: Yep. With plain jquery you use `$(sel).on('click', handler)` but in ember you would use actions. The documentation is here http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

Comment: Yes it makes perfect sense, I just wasn't being careful enough. I'm starting to see things in an Ember light but my confidence is still not fully there so I second guess and don't see things I normally would. I expect that will fill over the next few weeks. Anyway thanks for helping me get to the right answer.